# event.target.value is giving value before change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling

when i am trying to change the state of input field using onchange e.target.value is giving the value before change

```js
 <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input type='text'value={this.state.search} onChange={this.onChange}/>
      <button type='submit' >Search</button>
 </form>
```

the onchange function looks like this

```js
onChange=(e)=>{ var search=e.target.value;
    this.setState({search})
    this.props.dispatch({type:'SUGG',payload:this.state.search,})
}
```

I tried logging both `e.target.value` and `this.state.search` 
***e.target.value*** is showing correct value but state is showing previous value

edit: I got it setstate is async function so the previous value is getting logged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dispatching from callback of setState:

```
this.setState({search}, ()=>{
       this.props.dispatch({type:'SUGG',payload:this.state.search,})
});
```

It will update the state first then it will execute the callback because of the async nature of setState.

Comment: reason being because setState is asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

[@Jai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059101/jai)'s answer will work but assuming you don't have other operations that might modify `this.state.search` after calling `this.setState` you can just make the call to `dispatch` passing in `search` directly.

For example:

```
payload:search
```

And in full:

```
onChange=(e)=>{ var search=e.target.value;
    this.setState({search})
    this.props.dispatch({type:'SUGG',payload:search,})
}
```

The issue is that setState is asynchronous. Calling it does not immediately change `this.state` so you can either use `search` directly or use a callback in `setState`.